# What parameters affect the range and flight path of playing card? How?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinematics, rotational-kinematics, aerodynamics

An ordinary playing card can fly quite a long distance if you spin it during a throw.  What parameters affect the range and flight path?  How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very interesting question ! I don't know exact answer, but surely it has something to do with playing card angular rotation speed. The more it rotates faster - the less it will experience air resistance, aka. drag force. If rotation speed would be low or zero, then card will experience huge drag, because of tumbling which increases drag because of increased card's cross-section. Thus, it will fall down sooner. Of course card has no such parameter as angle of attack, but you can understand it's flight dynamics by studying [boomerang](http://boomlab.org/download/i/mark_dl/u/4013590225/4633773775/Boomlabf.pdf) flight laws